Count days from calendar dataframe based on dates from another dataframe
I have two dataframes:
df_tasks:



User
Start_Date
End_Date




1
2024-05-03
2024-05-15


2
2024-03-12
2024-04-27



df_calendar:



Date
Work_day




2024-03-01
True


2024-03-02
True


2024-03-03
False


2024-03-04
True



Workdays don't follow the normal calendar or holidays.
I want to know how many workdays are between the start and end dates of the first dataframe.
Expected output:



User
Start_Date
End_Date
Total_workdays




1
2024-05-03
2024-05-15
7


2
2024-03-12
2024-04-27
43



How can I achieve this in pandas?

Does this answer your question? Counting the business days between two series

@GeorginaSkibinski That example counts regular business days with a np function. In my case, I have a separate dataframe specifying which days are work days, which don't necessarily match standard business days or holidays.

You should be able to use the pandas .between function to extract the rows you need from the second dataframe.

You can use numpy broadcasting to compare the working dates do the start/end:
# ensure datetime
df_tasks[['Start_Date', 'End_Date']] = (df_tasks[['Start_Date', 'End_Date']]
                                        .apply(pd.to_datetime)
                                       )
df_calendar['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_calendar['Date'])

# convert to numpy
start = df_tasks[['Start_Date']].to_numpy()
end  = df_tasks[['End_Date']].to_numpy()
date = df_calendar.loc[df_calendar['Work_day'], 'Date'].to_numpy()

# broadcasted comparison and count
df_tasks['Total_workdays'] = ((start <= date) & (date <= end)).sum(axis=1)

Output with the provided data (+ an extra row for the demo):
   User Start_Date   End_Date  Total_workdays
0     1 2024-05-03 2024-05-15               0
1     2 2024-03-12 2024-04-27               0
2     3 2024-03-02 2024-03-10               2


depending on the data size i'd say conditional_join - you can even skip conditional_join and just compute the binary search

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_tasks = pd.DataFrame({
    'User': [1, 2],
    'Start_Date': ['1990-05-03', '1990-03-12'],
    'End_Date': ['1990-05-15', '1990-04-27']
})

df_calendar = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': pd.date_range(start='1990-03-01', end='1990-06-01'),
    'Work_day': [True, True, False, True, True, True, False,   # Mar 1 - Mar 7
                 True, True, True, False, True, True, True,  # Mar 8 - Mar 14
                 False, True, True, True, True, False, True,  # Mar 15 - Mar 21
                 True, True, True, False, True, True, True,  # Mar 22 - Mar 28
                 False, True, True, True, True, False, True,  # Mar 29 - Apr 4
                 True, True, True, False, True, True, True,  # Apr 5 - Apr 11
                 False, True, True, True, True, False, True,  # Apr 12 - Apr 18
                 True, True, True, False, True, True, True,  # Apr 19 - Apr 25
                 False, True, True, True, True, False, True,  # Apr 26 - May 2
                 True, True, True, False, True, True, True,  # May 3 - May 9
                 False, True, True, True, True, False, True,  # May 10 - May 16
                 True, True, True, False, True, True, True,  # May 17 - May 23
                 False, True, True, True, True, False, True,  # May 24 - May 30
                 True, False]  # May 31 - Jun 1
})

df_tasks[['Start_Date', 'End_Date']] = df_tasks[['Start_Date', 'End_Date']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
df_calendar['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_calendar['Date'])

start_dates = df_tasks['Start_Date'].values.astype('datetime64[D]')

end_dates = df_tasks['End_Date'].values.astype('datetime64[D]')

dates = df_calendar['Date'].values.astype('datetime64[D]')
work_days = df_calendar['Work_day'].values

m1 = (dates[:,None] >= start_dates)

m2 = (dates[:,None] <= end_dates)

mask = (m1 & m2)

total_work_days = (mask & work_days[:,None]).sum(axis=0)
print(total_work_days)#[10 37]

df_tasks['total_work_days'] = total_work_days
print(df_tasks)
"""
  User Start_Date   End_Date    total_work_days
0     1 1990-05-03 1990-05-15               10
1     2 1990-03-12 1990-04-27               37
"""

